# bad interpreter: No such file or directory after trying to create Gemset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I am trying the Rails tutorial in which we need to create a Gemset called 'rails_tutorial_rails_4_0'.

In order to do this we can run:

```
rvm use 2.0.0@railstutorial_rails_4_0 --create --default
```

in the terminal.

I get:

```
-bash: /Users/hmumin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/gem: /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Before I started the tutorial I changed my 'home' folder on my Mac from 'macbookpro' to 'hmumin'.

The error seems to not know which directory? If the issue is it not knowing where to point how do I get to point to the right directory?

Comment: You don't have `ruby-2.0.0-p353` installed. Use `rvm get latest; rvm install ruby-2.0.0`

Comment: when i do ruby -v i get ruby 2.0.0p247 doesn't that mean i have ruby installed?

Comment: That means you have an old patch installed. You need to either specify the old patch to be used, or you need to install the new patch. Note the `p247` and `p353`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the latest `ruby-2.0.0` installed.

You currently have `ruby-2.0.0-p247` installed. You are going to have to either specify the patch level that you want to use. In your case, you can use the command,

```
$ rvm use 2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0 --create --default
```

OR, my suggestion to you, would be to run

```
$ rvm get latest
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0
```

This will install the latest patch level, which will allow your previous command to work correctly.